# Rolling Annual Memberships aren't recording start dates

Tags: drupal, civimember

Any memberships recorded after a certain point do not have "member since" and "membership start" dates. Membership end date, however, is one year from the transaction date. We have upgraded recently from 4.3.8 to 4.7.15 but the dates do not seems to correlate with the upgrade exactly.

[image]

**Background**

The way our website is set up, and has been working successfully since launching the training feature last February, is that users with Drupal accounts may additionally subscribe for a membership which gives them access to a special training area. It's a flat-rate membership for unlimited access for one year from the time of subscribing (through a CiviMembership and CiviContribute page). Once the transaction is complete, the CiviMember Role Sync Module assigns them a special Drupal role.

We are using Drupal 7.50 and CiviCRM 4.7.15.

**Things I've Checked:**

- membership type settings are still set to annual rolling from time of sign up
  [image]
- I checked the membership status rules, but it seems that only new members are being affected, as we do not yet have renewals pouring in, it's too soon. 
  [image]
- Sample of new subscribers during the affected time frame and they do have the correct access and Drupal roles

Please let me know what other information I should include.

Comment: have you been able to replicate via front or rear end?

Comment: No and some memberships are still being recorded properly, which is the most perplexing thing about this.

Comment: have you double checked your Statuses - if you changed them at all - in case you have a break in the dates or some such

Comment: No status changes or anything. Not sure how to troubleshoot this. All memberships coming in at this point are missing start and join dates.

Comment: ping me on chat sometime for a screenshare if you want